# git date specification formats documentation?

Tags: git, date

Where can I find definitive documentation on all the date formats / expressions I'm allowed to use in e.g. `HEAD@{datespec}`?

For example, I just discovered I'm allowed to say not only `yesterday` (documented in `git-revisions` doc) but also e.g. `last.monday.morning`. How do I learn that, and all forms of legal date expression that can go here?

(It's *not* in the `git-revisions` doc. It's *not* in the `git-log` doc; I see that it tells me I can receive a relative date, but it doesn't tell me all the ways to *say* a relative date.)

Comment: I think you are looking for this : https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c

Comment: This might also help for date format specs : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800735/git-date-specification-formats-documentation. I haven't seen any proper documentation out there.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick Way cool, but what if I don't read C? :) I suspect that what you mean is, "it's not documented, your only choice is to read the source code". I'd be happy to accept that as an answer if that's just the way it is. Of course I think that's an unforgivable situation but I'm not here to whine but to establish the facts. I _thought_ I was right to suspect that this was not properly document, and you're confirming it.

Comment: BTW your second comment link leads me back to my own question. Aaaagh! :)

Comment: We all must agree that the git documentation is not up to mark,given the backing it has. We need to make it better at least for the beginners, sometimes even the most experienced ones find it frustrating. But I am definitely not the know-it-all guy, so I'm also hoping for someone to come up with a better answer. :)

Comment: my bad, but the second comment might be helpful to any future visitors(mostly intended for beginners who face problems while framing their questions correctly).

Comment: yeah, I'd say the `approxidate` and `relative` stuff is what I was particularly interested in; this explains why I can say e.g. `git log HEAD@{last.monday.morning}`. I think your answer ("look in the source code") is the right answer and you should give it so I can accept it. :)

Comment: I did. I'm glad it made you happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like currently there's **no proper documentation** out there that can serve your purpose.

So, in order to get your concern **(** and similar concerns of others **)** addressed, the **only place (as of now)** you can go to is the **code base** itself and find out **(** *which in itself is another question for beginners, as to how to navigate the source code and dig deeper just to find the allowed **expressions**/**values**/**codes** buried somewhere deep in the source code* **)**, additionally learn some **C/perl/bash/python and other things** just to understand the source code.

Long story short, [this-thing-here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/date.c) can help you.