# How to target a commit from N days ago in git?

Tags: git, squash

I'm using a private GitHub repo as a backup for some notes I'm taking, and I have a script setup to automatically make commits and push them every 10 minutes while I'm working, if any changes are detected. Since I tend to be writing notes for 1-2 hours a day, after a week I'll have somewhere between 50-90 commits, and I don't want/need my commit history to be that numerous.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git) and saw its most upvoted answer:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3 &&
git commit
```

This is really close to what I need, but I want to target the commit 7 (or N) ***days*** ago rather than pick some N number of ***commits*** ago. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "is there a way in git to target the commit 7 days ago" Yes, there is. For instance `HEAD@{7.days.ago}`

Comment: @matt beautiful, thanks! I'll work on putting together a script and answer this question with it when I'm done.

Comment: You can omit the dots and use spaces instead. Git is astoundingly forgiving about date specifications. Documentation is however very poor. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800735/git-date-specification-formats-documentation